# Use of Typed dataset in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have added a typed DataSet using Add>>> DataSet and configured it to connect with my SQLDatabase.  Also, it has created Delete, UpDate, Select etc. commands.

At this stage, in winform formload event, I could always find a statment something like
`taTest.fill(dsTest.tblData)` so I could use dsTest.tblData for reading, writing my data.
But I donot find anything like this in ASP.Net.
My question is what is the use of this DataSet and how can I use it like we do in winforms.

For example if need

```
msgbox (dsTest.tblData.rows.count)
```

it works in winforms but not in asp.net

Comment: Forget about MsgBox in web development. just not there.

Answer (score 0):

Look you can use the dataset pretty much in the same way, just careful that asp.net webforms are stateless.

Start putting the code to load the data inside page_load event, debug it and check if data is loaded. then you can bind it to grids or controls and call grid.DataBind() to see it.

Comment: I tried  lable.Test=ds.Tables(0).rows.count but it gives error on
ds.Tables

Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference.

Comment: Can you suggest how I can perform this operation.  I alos need dim a as integer=ds.Tables(0).rows.coun

Comment: I just added Dataset by right clicking my project in the solution explorer.  Then configured dataset.  I donot know how this dataset will be linked with my default.aspx as I am coding in default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

hejdig.

**Short answer to question:**
I guess you are mixing the class and the object.

**Longer rant:**
Your example

```
 lable.Test=ds.Tables(0).rows.count
```

probably is

```
 lable.Text=ds.Tables(0).rows.count
```

(don't rewrite code - copy/paste it, code that looks  bad will get you fewer responses)

and then ds probably is your class, not your object.
try

```
Dim myDataset = New ds()
...whatever magic like myDataset.Tables(0).fill
lable.Text = myDataset.Tables(0).Rows.Count
```

---

Here are a few more hints when I am already writing:
Datasets work the same in fat clients (webforms/wpf) and web(webforms/aspnet).
You have a *typed dataset* which is considered good.  Use its types.  For instance

```
lable.Text = myDataset.MyTable.Rows.Count
```

is probably better than referencing the first table [table(0)]
It seems you are doing something called tableadapters - that is using an old and out of date framework for reading data into datatables.  In short: Don't.  I have at least 2 systems using that technology and it sucks big time.  Small buttons to press for updating data, bad overview when datasets get big, bugs in the IDE dropping your layout and a very sensitive XML behind it all.
But don't give up on datasets/datatables.  Those are good.  Much of the critique on datasets/datatables stems from people using tableadapters and blaming it on datasets/datatables.
If you are diving into datasets/datatables do use the partial class functionality.  When you are *inside* the class you have more functionality like properties and events.

/OF